# pgAdmin III (pgadmin3_92.x86_64 0:1.16.1-1.rhel6 ) won't start

Tags: postgresql, centos, pgadmin

- OS on which I've isntalled pgAdmin: Centos 6.3
- Postgresql 9.2 is installed on another machine (not sure if this matters)

Have installed `pgadmin3_92` via postgresql repo.

When I go: `Applications > Programming > pgAdminIII`, and select, nothing happens.

When I enter `pgadmin3_92` into the terminal I get

> pgadmin3_92: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've tried a Google search for this error and it came back with no results. I'm only new with Linux/Centos so I've reached the limit of what to do next to figure out how to get pgAdminIII working.

Any ideas on what to look for/do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by Centos not being able to find the shared libraries to run the application.

My `pgadmin3` library files are installed at: `/usr/pgsql-9.2/lib`

I ran `ldd pgadmin3` as per hints [here](http://innovationsts.com/?p=1042), this confirmed that the shared library could not be found to run `pgadmin`.

Also on the same link it shows to change to root user: `su - root`, and then create a `.conf` file that points Centos to where the libraries are for `pgadmin3`. The command to create this file is:

```
echo /usr/pgsql-9.2/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/pgsql-9.2.conf
```

For someone else this would be:

```
echo <location of pgadmin3 libraries> > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/pgsql-9.2.conf
```

I then ran: `cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/pgsql-9.2.conf` to confirm the file had been created and the location of the libraries had been written to the file.

I then ran the following to ensure Centos was refreshed with this new configuration info:

```
/sbin/ldconfig
```

I was able to run `pgadmin3` after this.

Answer (score -1):

```
yum install postgresql92
```

If it is not enough then

```
yum install postgresql92-libs
```

Comment: Have run `yum install postgresql92` with success, `pgadmin` still wouldn't start (same error message). Tried `yum install postgresql92-libs` and was told already installed. So unfortunately this hasn't worked for me.